# How to create dynamically Resizable shapes in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have three problems:

1. I want to create resizable shapes with box bounding...
2. I also want to know how to get child seleted in a Pane.
3. I'm  creating multiple shapes on a pane. I want to change some property of that shape say Fill.. How do i do it??

Thanx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Next example will answer your questions:

- for (1) it uses binding, connecting pane size with rectangle size
- for (2) it adds `setOnMouseClick` for each rectangle which stores clicked one in the `lastOne` field.
- for (3) see code of `setOnMouseClick()` handler

  ```
  public class RectangleGrid extends Application {

    private Rectangle lastOne;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      Pane root = new Pane();

      int grid_x = 7; //number of rows
      int grid_y = 7; //number of columns

      // this binding will find out which parameter is smaller: height or width
      NumberBinding rectsAreaSize = Bindings.min(root.heightProperty(), root.widthProperty());

      for (int x = 0; x < grid_x; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < grid_y; y++) {
              Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
              rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

              rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                      if (lastOne != null) {
                          lastOne.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                      }
                      // remembering clicks
                      lastOne = (Rectangle) t.getSource();
                      // updating fill
                      lastOne.setFill(Color.RED);
                  }
              });

              // here we position rects (this depends on pane size as well)
              rectangle.xProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(x).divide(grid_x));
              rectangle.yProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.multiply(y).divide(grid_y));

              // here we bind rectangle size to pane size 
              rectangle.heightProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(grid_x));
              rectangle.widthProperty().bind(rectangle.heightProperty());

              root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
          }
      }

      stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
      stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
  }
  ```