# How to listen for resize events in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

How can I detect when a Scene or Stage changes size in JavaFX 2.1? I cannot find any EventHandler for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are `heightProperty` and `widthProperty`. You can use these properties for binding, or add listeners to them.

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 300, 200);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.titleProperty().bind(
            scene.widthProperty().asString().
            concat(" : ").
            concat(scene.heightProperty().asString()));

    stage.show();
}
```

Or see next example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893911/1054140

Comment: Sergey, could you say if there is a solution to get stage resize event when user releases left mouse button? There is a solution from Chris however it lets only to decrease number of events but doesn't let get only one event.

Comment: @PavelK please make a separate question with more details. I don't understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159794/get-single-stage-resize-event-when-user-releases-left-mouse-button

Answer (score 11):

A way to perform an action **after re-sizing** a scene was finished you can do this:

(Note: there maybe better ways to do this, for me it did the job)

```
final Stage primaryStage = getStage() // get your stage from somewhere

// create a listener
final ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>()
{
  final Timer timer = new Timer(); // uses a timer to call your resize method
  TimerTask task = null; // task to execute after defined delay
  final long delayTime = 200; // delay that has to pass in order to consider an operation done

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, final Number newValue)
  {
    if (task != null)
    { // there was already a task scheduled from the previous operation ...
      task.cancel(); // cancel it, we have a new size to consider
    }

    task = new TimerTask() // create new task that calls your resize operation
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      { 
        // here you can place your resize code
        System.out.println("resize to " + primaryStage.getWidth() + " " + primaryStage.getHeight());
      }
    };
    // schedule new task
    timer.schedule(task, delayTime);
  }
};

// finally we have to register the listener
primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
```

Comment: Plus one for solution with timer task. Very nice ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this make the application still run after closing it ?

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution.

Comment: +Jacks You can set a Timer to be deamon in the constructor, that should solve it. Btw, this answer really should be posted on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159794/get-single-stage-resize-event-when-user-releases-left-mouse-button

Answer (score 2):

this is too old and basic but it might help a noob like me

you can add a listener to width and height properties

```
stage.heightProperty().addListener(e ->{
    handle....
});

stage.widthProperty().addListener(e ->{
    handle....
});
```

Comment: correct. But the solution of Chris uses that, too. Additionally his solution manages to reduce the number of changes. In your case at least two times the code in the listener would be run, in his version only once.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein agreed, this seemed like the easy way to go 2 years ago in a simple GUI