# Get single stage resize event when user releases left mouse button

Tags: java, javafx

I've googled enough but still can find solution to get only single resize event when user releases left mouse button. For example the following solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774249/5057736)

```
stage.titleProperty().bind(
        scene.widthProperty().asString().
        concat(" : ").
        concat(scene.heightProperty().asString()));
```

When user clicks mouse left button and starts resizing the stage we will get very many events (using property listeners) while he does resizing. However, I want to get only one event - when the user completes resizing and releases mouse left button.

Another solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812859/5057736) This solution significantly decreases amount of events but still doesn't let to get only one.

How to get only one resize event after user releases mouse button?

Comment: What’s wrong with the second solution?  Why is it so important to get only one event?  What’s wrong with getting, say, five events?

Comment: @VGR Because I need to do heavy operation (read from database) and I don't want to do it five times.

Comment: What about using the second solution with a longer delay, like 1000 milliseconds?  (That second solution is out of date;  you should use a ScheduledExecutorService rather than a TimerTask, but the principle is the same.)

Comment: @VGR Yes, different variations are possible but I want to do normal solution without workarounds.

Comment: Have you actually implemented any of the ideas you are against to see how they perform, or have you just decided that you are not going to implement them because of the perceived heavy operation.

Comment: A `PauseTransition` is probably sufficient, and much simpler to use than either a `ScheduledExecutorService` or a `TimerTask`. I don't think there's a way to achieve what you're actually asking for: the mouse events for resizing the window are handled natively and aren't available to JavaFX, AFAIK.

Comment: If it's important not to schedule too many requests for the work that you need to do, you should implement a solution for *that*, rather than trying to intercept user events anyway. E.g. schedule a *request* for the work, and only process one request at a time. When the stage changes size, replace the existing request if one exists.

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson I implemented both of them. Trust me. However, I want to get one event.

Comment: IMHO<Unless you want to write native libs for you application to hook to system events your best shot here is timer approach.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the mouse event handlers that resize the stage are managed natively, and so there is no way to access those purely in JavaFX - to do this the way you describe would require writing native libraries and hooking into them.

If you are doing some heavy computation (or other work that takes a long time) in response to the change in size of the stage, your best bet is probably to write code that only processes one change at a time, and just processes the last known change when it can.

An example of this is:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageResizeThrottling extends Application {

    private Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BlockingQueue<Point2D> dimensionChangeQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        ChangeListener<Number> dimensionChangeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dimensionChangeQueue.clear();
            dimensionChangeQueue.add(new Point2D(primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()));
        };
        primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(dimensionChangeListener);
        primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(dimensionChangeListener);

        Thread processDimensionChangeThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for change in size");
                    Point2D size = dimensionChangeQueue.take();
                    System.out.printf("Detected change in size to [%.1f, %.1f]: processing%n", size.getX(), size.getY());
                    process(size, primaryStage);
                    System.out.println("Done processing");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException letThreadExit) { }
        });
        processDimensionChangeThread.setDaemon(true);
        processDimensionChangeThread.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void process(Point2D stageDimension, Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {
        // simulate slow process:
        Thread.sleep(500 + rng.nextInt(1000));
        final String title = String.format("Width: %.0f Height: %.0f", stageDimension.getX(), stageDimension.getY());
        Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setTitle(title));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that this will always process the very first change immediately, and then process the latest change when each previously-processed change has finished processing. If no further changes have occurred, it will wait until one does occur and then process it immediately. If you like, you can combine this with the timer-based technique you linked for coalescing the changes in the listener, which will typically remove the very first change that is processed (which is usually redundant as it is almost always followed by subsequent changes). The following changes will wait until no resizes have occurred for 300ms before submitting one to the queue for processing (the thread still behaves the same way - it will process the latest change, and when that processing is complete, wait for another one):

```
    BlockingQueue<Point2D> dimensionChangeQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

    PauseTransition coalesceChanges = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(300));
    coalesceChanges.setOnFinished(e -> {
        dimensionChangeQueue.clear();
        dimensionChangeQueue.add(new Point2D(primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()));           
    });

    ChangeListener<Number> dimensionChangeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        coalesceChanges.playFromStart();

    primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(dimensionChangeListener);
    primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(dimensionChangeListener);
```

There's some tuning here, which is a tradeoff between latency and over-eagerness in processing changes. You probably want the pause transition to last something shorter than the average processing time of the change in screen size, but not an order of magnitude shorter.

The code guarantees that no more than one change will be processed at a time and that the latest change will eventually be processed if no more changes occur. This is probably about as good as you can get without accessing native user events. (And it would also handle programmatic changes in the stage size, which a mouse handler would not handle.)

Comment: @PavelK Arguably this doesn't really answer the question you asked, but perhaps it gives a route to do what you actually want to do with a better degree of efficiency than the solution you already cited.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am sure that it will be useful not only for me but and for others.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create an example to achieve what you are looking for, I ended up with this, it is not perfect but when I tested it, it looked like it could help:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class OneEventJavaFX extends Application{
    double originalWidth = 400;  // the initial width of Scene when the program starts
    double originalHeight = 400; // the initial height of Scene when the program starts

    // boolean property to be observed in order to know the completion of stage resize
    BooleanProperty completedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false); 
    Timeline timeline; 

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Pane root = new Pane(); // simple root as example just for test purpose
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400,400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("OneEventJavaFX");
    stage.show();


    // because I could not find a way to implement MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED
    // on the stage to notify the completion on resizing, I had to use a TimeLine 
    // the duration should consider the time the user usually take to finish every resize 
    // duration is tricky, Very Slow Resizing V.S Very Fast Resizing!

    timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e ->{
                        System.out.println("Resizing Should Be Completed By Now!");
                        originalWidth = scene.getWidth(); // record the new scene size
                        originalHeight = scene.getHeight();
                        completedProperty.setValue(false);
                        }));

    // change listener, to be added to and removed from the scene
    ChangeListener<Number> changeListener= (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->{
        System.out.println("I am Detecting an Event!"); // test

        // once the size changed
        if(originalWidth-scene.getWidth()>1 || scene.getWidth()-originalWidth>1 ||
            originalHeight-scene.getHeight()>1 || scene.getHeight()-originalHeight>1){

            completedProperty.set(true); // notify that completion should be considered
            System.out.println("I Stopped! No More Events!");
            timeline.play(); // and start counting the time 
        }};


     // add the change listener when the program starts up
     scene.widthProperty().addListener(changeListener); 
     scene.heightProperty().addListener(changeListener);
     System.out.println("ChangeListener Added At Startup!");


     // now listen to the change of the boolean property value
     // instead of the size changes, it should NOT take a lot of work
     // then accordingly add and remove change listener!
     completedProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

       @Override
       public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, 
                                  Boolean notComplete, Boolean complete) {
             if (complete) {
                 scene.widthProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                 scene.heightProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                 System.out.println("ChangeListener Removed!");
             }
             else{
                 scene.widthProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                 scene.heightProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                 System.out.println("ChangeListener Added Back!");
             }
         }
     });
 }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch();
   }

}
```

**Test While Resizing**

```
ChangeListener Added At Startup!
I am Detecting an Event!
I am Detecting an Event!
ChangeListener Removed!
I Stopped! No More Events!
Resizing Should Be Completed By Now!
ChangeListener Added Back!
```

---

---

**UPDATE:**

I have been working on solving this question, I believe this approach can achieve what you want.

**The idea is as follows:**

1. Create *UNDECORATED* **Stage** and Make it *Resizable*.
2. Create a **Title Bar** and add it to the **Stage**.
3. Now the **Mouse Events** can be *detected* on the **Border** of the **Stage** (because basically it happens on the **Scene**).
4. Create **Double Property** for both the **Width** and **Height** of **Stage** and add **Change Listener** to listen to the Changes.
5. The changes in the Stage Width & Height will only be **recorded** at the **beginning** of the drag and when user **RELEASES** the Mouse.
6. Explanations in Comments.
7. The whole solution can be found [here](https://github.com/John-Almardeny/One-Event-Stage-JavaFX) as an archive file (Why? Because I tried to post it here fully but the Body Limit is *30000* Character!) .

---

**OneEventStage Class:**

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


/**
 * This class customize a given Stage to record the changes 
 * of its size only when user starts and finishes resizing (recording one event)
 * @author Yahya Almardeny
 * @version 28/05/2017
 */
public class OneEventStage{
    private double originalWidth;  // the initial width of Scene when the program starts
    private double originalHeight; // the initial height of Scene when the program starts
    private TitleBar titleBar; // can be customized by the setter method (by default I made it for Windows 10 style)
    private boolean started, alreadyFullScreen;
    private DoubleProperty widthChange, heightChange; // record the changes in size
    public Scene s;
    public BorderPane scene; // this will be considered as a Scene when used in the program

    public OneEventStage(Stage stage, double width, double height){
        originalWidth = width; originalHeight = height;

        widthChange = new SimpleDoubleProperty(originalWidth);
        heightChange = new SimpleDoubleProperty(originalHeight);

        started = false;
        titleBar = new TitleBar("");

        scene = new BorderPane();
        scene.setTop(titleBar.getTitleBar());

        s = new Scene(scene, originalWidth,originalHeight);

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        stage.setScene(s);

        ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(stage);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){   
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // change listener, to be added to and removed from the scene
                        ChangeListener<Number> changeListener= (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->{
                            if(isFullScreen()){
                                widthChange.setValue(stage.getWidth());
                                heightChange.setValue(stage.getHeight());
                                alreadyFullScreen=true;
                            }

                            else if (alreadyFullScreen){ // coming from full screen mode
                                widthChange.setValue(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());
                                heightChange.setValue(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight());
                                widthChange.setValue(originalWidth);
                                heightChange.setValue(originalHeight);
                                alreadyFullScreen = false;
                            }
                            else if(!alreadyFullScreen && !started){
                                started = true; // to inform the detecting Mouse Release Event is required
                            }
                        };

                        s.setOnMouseReleased(e->{
                            if(started){ // if this happens particularly after changing the size/dragging
                                originalWidth = stage.getWidth(); // record the new scene size 
                                originalHeight = stage.getHeight();
                                widthChange.setValue(originalWidth); // add it
                                heightChange.setValue(originalHeight);
                                started = false;
                            }
                        });


                        // add the change listener when the program starts up
                        s.widthProperty().addListener(changeListener); 
                        s.heightProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                    }

                });
                return null;
            }};
        new Thread(task).start();

    }

    /*
     * to detected if user clicked on maximize button or double click on the title bar
     */
    private boolean isFullScreen(){
        return this.s.getWindow().getWidth()==Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() &&
               this.s.getWindow().getHeight()==Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
    }


    public DoubleProperty getWidthChange() {
        return widthChange;
    }

    public DoubleProperty getHeightChange() {
        return heightChange;
    }

    public TitleBar getTitleBar() {
        return titleBar;
    }


    public void setTitleBar(TitleBar titleBar) {
        this.titleBar = titleBar;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
       titleBar.getTitle().setText(title);
    }


}
```

---

**OneEventStageTest Class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * Implementing an Example of OneEventStage to test it
 * @author Yahya Almardeny
 * @version 28/05/2017
 */
public class OneEventStageTest extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // create stage
        OneEventStage stage = new OneEventStage(primaryStage, 400,400); 
        stage.setTitle("One Event Stage");

        // simple containers and its components for testing purpose
        VBox container = new VBox();
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox widthInfoContainer = new HBox();
        widthInfoContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label widthChangeL = new Label("Width Changes");
        TextField widthChangeV = new TextField();
        widthChangeV.setEditable(false);
        widthInfoContainer.getChildren().addAll(widthChangeL, widthChangeV);
        HBox.setMargin(widthChangeL, new Insets(10));
        HBox.setMargin(widthChangeV, new Insets(10));

        HBox heightInfoContainer = new HBox();
        heightInfoContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label heightChangeL = new Label("Height Changes");
        TextField heightChangeV = new TextField();
        heightChangeV.setEditable(false);
        heightInfoContainer.getChildren().addAll(heightChangeL, heightChangeV);
        HBox.setMargin(heightChangeL, new Insets(10));
        HBox.setMargin(heightChangeV, new Insets(10));

        container.getChildren().addAll(widthInfoContainer, heightInfoContainer);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        DoubleProperty widthChange = stage.getWidthChange();
        DoubleProperty heightChange = stage.getHeightChange();


        // listen to the changes (Testing)
        widthChange.addListener((obs, old, newV)->{
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    widthChangeV.setText("From(" + old.doubleValue() + ")  To(" + newV.doubleValue() + ")");

                }

            });

        });

        heightChange.addListener((obs, old, newV)->{
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    heightChangeV.setText("From(" + old.doubleValue() + ") To(" + newV.doubleValue() + ")");

                }

            });

        });

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // represent a root but in fact it's inside the real root (BorderPane in the OneEventStage Class!).
        StackPane root = new StackPane(); 
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(container);
        stage.scene.setCenter(root);

        primaryStage.show();    
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


}
```

---

**TitleBar Class:**

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * This class to create a default/customized Title Bar 
 * to be added to Undecorated Stage in JavaFX Application
 * @author Yahya Almardeny
 * @version 27/05/2017
 */
public class TitleBar {
    private HBox titleBar;
    private ImageView icon;
    private StackPane close, minimize, maximize; // represent customized components for the title bar (by using the second constructor)
    private Image maximizeBefore, maximizeAfter; // for changing maximize icon when it's full screen
    private Label title;
    private double height, stageWidth, stageHeight, x,y, offsetX, offsetY;
    private double screenWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth(), 
                   screenHeight = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
    private Color backgroundColor;
    private StackPane maximizeButton; // for default title bar
    private Label minimizeButton, closeButton; // for default title bar
    private Stage stage;
    private boolean intialized = false, fromMax = false;

    public static enum Components {ICON,TITLE,MINIMIZE,MAXIMIZE,CLOSE;}

    /**
     * the default constructor, appearance of Windows 10
     * @param title
     */
    public TitleBar(String title){
        titleBar = new HBox();

        icon =  new ImageView(new Image(TitleBar.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon/icon.png")));
        icon.setFitWidth(15); this.icon.setFitHeight(13); 

        closeButton = new Label("×");
        closeButton.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", 25));
        closeButton.setPrefWidth(46);
        closeButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        minimizeButton = new Label("—");
        minimizeButton.setFont(Font.font(10));
        minimizeButton.setPrefWidth(46);
        minimizeButton.setPrefHeight(29);

        minimizeButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        maximizeButton = maximiazeButton();

        this.title = new Label(title);

        final Pane space = new Pane();
        HBox.setHgrow(space,Priority.ALWAYS);

        titleBar.getChildren().addAll(this.icon, this.title,space,this.minimizeButton, this.maximizeButton, this.closeButton);
        titleBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        HBox.setMargin(this.icon, new Insets(0,5,0,10)); // top,right, bottom, left

        initalize(); // private method to get the Stage for first time
        setDefaultControlsFunctionality(); // private method to add the default controls functionality

    }


    /**
     * This is constructor to create a custom title bar
     * @param icon
     * @param minimize
     * @param maximize
     * @param close
     * @param title
     */
    public TitleBar(Image icon, Image minimize, Image maximizeBefore, Image maximizeAfter, Image close, String title){
        titleBar = new HBox();

        this.icon =  new ImageView(icon);
        this.icon.setFitWidth(15); this.icon.setFitHeight(14);  // values can be changed via setters

        this.close = new StackPane();
        this.close.setPrefSize(25, 20);
        this.close.getChildren().add(new ImageView(close));
        ((ImageView) this.close.getChildren().get(0)).setFitWidth(20);
        ((ImageView) this.close.getChildren().get(0)).setFitHeight(20);

        this.minimize = new StackPane();
        this.minimize.setPrefSize(25, 20);
        this.minimize.getChildren().add(new ImageView(minimize));
        ((ImageView) this.minimize.getChildren().get(0)).setFitWidth(20);
        ((ImageView) this.minimize.getChildren().get(0)).setFitHeight(20);

        this.maximizeBefore = maximizeBefore;
        this.maximize = new StackPane();
        this.maximize.setPrefSize(25, 20);
        this.maximize.getChildren().add(new ImageView(maximizeBefore));
        ((ImageView) this.maximize.getChildren().get(0)).setFitWidth(20);
        ((ImageView) this.maximize.getChildren().get(0)).setFitHeight(20);
        this.maximizeAfter = maximizeAfter;

        this.title = new Label(title);

        final Pane space = new Pane();
        HBox.setHgrow(space,Priority.ALWAYS);

        titleBar.getChildren().addAll(this.icon, this.title,space,this.minimize, this.maximize, this.close);
        titleBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        HBox.setMargin(this.icon, new Insets(0,5,0,10)); // top,right, bottom, left
        HBox.setMargin(this.close, new Insets(0,5,0,0));

        initalize();
        setCustomizedControlsFunctionality();
    }



    /**
     * create the default maximize button
     * @return container
     */
    private StackPane maximiazeButton(){
        StackPane container = new StackPane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(8,8);
        rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        container.setPrefWidth(46);
        container.getChildren().add(rect);  

        return container;
    }



    /**
     * To get the Stage of the application for one time only
     * as well as adding listener to iconifiedProperty()
     */
    private void initalize(){
       titleBar.setOnMouseEntered(e->{ // the entire block will be executed only once
          if(!intialized){
             // get the stage and assign it to the Stage field
             stage = ((Stage)titleBar.getScene().getWindow());

             // add listener toiconifiedProperty()
             stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(ee->{
                 if(!stage.isIconified()){ 
                    stage.setMaximized(true);
                    if(fromMax){ // if already maximized
                       stage.setWidth(screenWidth);
                       stage.setHeight(screenHeight);
                       stage.setX(0);
                       stage.setY(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        stage.setWidth(stageWidth);
                        stage.setHeight(stageHeight);
                        stage.setX(x);
                        stage.setY(y);
                    }
                    try { // to remove the flash
                         Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    stage.setOpacity(1.0);
                 }
            });


            intialized=true;
         }
       });  
    }


    /**
     * To add functionality to title bar controls
     * via event listeners
     */
    private void setDefaultControlsFunctionality(){

        // Double-Click on Title Bar
        titleBar.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(e.getClickCount()==2){
                maximizefunctonality();
            }       
        });

        //Maximize Control
        maximizeButton.setOnMouseEntered(e->{// highlight when hover    
            maximizeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY,null,null)));
                ((Rectangle)maximizeButton.getChildren().get(0)).setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                if(maximizeButton.getChildren().size()==2){
                   ((Rectangle)maximizeButton.getChildren().get(1)).setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                }

        });
        maximizeButton.setOnMouseExited(e->{ // remove highlight 
            maximizeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT,null,null)));
               ((Rectangle)maximizeButton.getChildren().get(0)).setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               if(maximizeButton.getChildren().size()==2){
                  ((Rectangle)maximizeButton.getChildren().get(1)).setFill(Color.WHITE);
                }
        });
        maximizeButton.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            maximizefunctonality();

        });

        //Close Control
        closeButton.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
            closeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CRIMSON,null,null)));
                closeButton.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        });
        closeButton.setOnMouseExited(e->{
            closeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT,null,null)));
                closeButton.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        });

        closeButton.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            stage.close();  
        });


        //Minimize Control
        minimizeButton.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
            minimizeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY,null,null))); 
        });
        minimizeButton.setOnMouseExited(e->{
            minimizeButton.setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT,null,null)));
        });
        minimizeButton.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(!stage.isIconified()){ // if it's not minimized
                if(fromMax){ // check if it's already full screen(maximized)
                    stage.setOpacity(0.0);
                    stage.setIconified(true); // minimize it
                }
                else{ // if it's not -> record the size and position
                    stageWidth = stage.getWidth();
                    stageHeight = stage.getHeight();
                    x = stage.getX();
                    y = stage.getY();
                    stage.setOpacity(0.0);
                    stage.setIconified(true); // minimize it
                }
            }
        });

        // to make title bar movable
        titleBar.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth || stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
                offsetX = e.getScreenX() - stage.getX();
                offsetY = e.getScreenY() - stage.getY();
            }
        });
        titleBar.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth || stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
                stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - offsetX);
                stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - offsetY);
            }
        });

    }



    private void maximizefunctonality(){
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) maximizeButton.getChildren().get(0);
        if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth||stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
            // get the previous size + position
            stageWidth = stage.getWidth();
            stageHeight = stage.getHeight();
            x = stage.getX();
            y = stage.getY();
            // maximize it
            stage.setWidth(screenWidth);
            stage.setHeight(screenHeight);
            stage.centerOnScreen();

            // change the maximize button appearance
            rect.setTranslateX(2);
            rect.setTranslateY(-2);
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(8,8);
            rect1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            maximizeButton.getChildren().add(rect1);

            fromMax = true;
        }
        else{ // if already maximized -> return to previous size + position
            stage.setWidth(stageWidth);
            stage.setHeight(stageHeight);
            stage.setX(x);
            stage.setY(y);  
            fromMax = false;

            // change the maximize button appearance
            rect.setTranslateX(0);
            rect.setTranslateY(0);
            maximizeButton.getChildren().remove(1);
        }

    }



    private void setCustomizedControlsFunctionality(){

        //Maximize Control
        maximize.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth||stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
                // get the previous size + position
                stageWidth = stage.getWidth();
                stageHeight = stage.getHeight();
                x = stage.getX();
                y = stage.getY();
                // maximize it
                stage.setWidth(screenWidth);
                stage.setHeight(screenHeight);
                stage.centerOnScreen();

                // change the maximize button appearance
                ((ImageView) maximize.getChildren().get(0)).setImage(maximizeAfter);

                fromMax = true;
            }
            else{ // if already maximized -> return to previous size + position
                stage.setWidth(stageWidth);
                stage.setHeight(stageHeight);
                stage.setX(x);
                stage.setY(y);  
                fromMax = false;

                // change the maximize button appearance
                ((ImageView) maximize.getChildren().get(0)).setImage(maximizeBefore);
            }

        });

        close.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            stage.close();  
        });


        //Minimize Control
        minimize.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(!stage.isIconified()){ // if it's not minimized
                if(fromMax){ // check if it's already full screen(maximized)
                    stage.setOpacity(0.0);
                    stage.setIconified(true); // minimize it
                }
                else{ // if it's not -> record the size and position
                    stageWidth = stage.getWidth();
                    stageHeight = stage.getHeight();
                    x = stage.getX();
                    y = stage.getY();
                    stage.setOpacity(0.0);
                    stage.setIconified(true); // minimize it
                }
            }
        });

        // to make title bar movable
        titleBar.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth || stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
                offsetX = e.getScreenX() - stage.getX();
                offsetY = e.getScreenY() - stage.getY();
            }
        });
        titleBar.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            if(stage.getWidth()<screenWidth || stage.getHeight()<screenHeight){
                stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - offsetX);
                stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - offsetY);
            }
        });

    }



    /**
     * To change margins/insets to the Title Bar components
     * @param component
     * @param top
     * @param right
     * @param bottom
     * @param left
     */
    public void setInsets(Components component, double top, double right, double bottom, double left){
        switch(component){
        case TITLE:
            HBox.setMargin(title, new Insets(top, right, bottom ,left));
            break;
        case ICON:
            HBox.setMargin(icon, new Insets(top, right, bottom ,left));
            break;
        case CLOSE:
            HBox.setMargin(close, new Insets(top, right, bottom ,left));
            break;
        case MAXIMIZE:
            HBox.setMargin(maximize, new Insets(top, right, bottom ,left));
            break;
        case MINIMIZE:
            HBox.setMargin(minimize, new Insets(top, right, bottom ,left));
            break;
        }
    }



    public void setControlsSpace(Components component, double width, double height){
        switch(component){

        case CLOSE:
            close.setPrefSize(width, height);
            break;
        case MAXIMIZE:
            maximize.setPrefSize(width, height);
            break;
        case MINIMIZE:
            minimize.setPrefSize(width, height);
            break;
        case TITLE:
            //do nothing
            break;
        case ICON:
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
    }


    public void addHoverEffect(Components component, Color defaultColor, Color onHover, Cursor cursor){

    }

    //reset of the class
    {...}

}
```

---

**ResizeHelper Class:**

```
{....}
```

---

**Test**
[image]

Comment: Hmm. Isn't this just a different implementation of the timer-based strategy in the solution linked in the OP (just using a timeline instead of a java.util.Timer)?

Comment: @James_D Hmm. I have not looked at the solution linked in the OP, as you can see from my comment before the `TimeLine`. However, I like your enthusiasm to answering all `JavaFX` questions on SO :)

Comment: @James_D What is your opinion bout this idea/approach? It's very important to me please.

Comment: If the application specs allow for a non-standard window (i.e. one that doesn't have the system title bar, border, etc), this approach - essentially allowing you to track the mouse events directly - seems good. I haven't read all the code, but the idea seems ok to me.